# Distributional logarithm

Tags: distribution-theory

I am reading Distribution Theory courently but there is part that I can't pass:

[image]

Last equation in $(1.204)$ makes no sence for me becouse as far as I know:

$\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon}\phi(x)ln|x|dx=-\int^{-\infty}_{-\epsilon}\phi(x)ln|x|dx=-\int^{-\infty}_{-\epsilon}\phi(x)ln(-x)dx=|t=-x,dx=-dt|=-\int^{\infty}_{\epsilon} \phi(-t)ln(t)(-1)dt=\int^{\infty}_{\epsilon}\phi(-t)ln(t)dt $

so where from is the minus in last formula?

Comment: From a mistake. As you found, it ought to be a $+$. That doesn't change the conclusion that we have a distribution, however.

Answer (score 3):

You are completely right, it ought to be $[\varphi(x) + \varphi(-x)]$ in that formula, the "$-$" is a mistake. The conclusion that

$$\varphi \mapsto \int_\mathbb{R} \varphi(x)\ln \lvert x\rvert\,dx$$

is a distribution is unaffected, however.

Comment: And how in that case can I justify the convergence of integral and lately or maby at the same time continuity ?

Comment: $x\mapsto \ln x$ is integrable on $[0,a]$, and $x\mapsto \varphi(x) + \varphi(-x)$ is bounded. I don't see a reason to rewrite the integral, since everything is automatic with $$\int_{[-a,a]} \varphi(x)\ln \lvert x\rvert\,dx,$$ the dominated convergence theorem gives the continuity directly. But if the author prefers rewriting the integral, that works too.

Comment: You are right, it is clear now. Thanks.

Comment: One mor question, is it still right that derivative of that is P.V.1/x ? I ask because something is strange for me, author makes that mistake with sign for couple of pages and calculates everythig with help of that.

Comment: Yes, that is still right. When you integrate by parts from $$\int_{\varepsilon}^a [\varphi'(x) + \varphi'(-x)]\ln x\,dx,$$ then you get $[\varphi(x) -\varphi(-x)]\frac{1}{x}$ as the integrand. While I was in the bath, it occurred to me that that might have been the reason to rewrite the integral and led to the sign error.